# Let $p=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ how can I add $a_{n+1}x^{n+1},a_{n+2}x^{n+2},...$ while maintaining some properties?

Tags: polynomials, roots

> Let $p_n=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ be a polynomial with only real roots.
>
> I need a way to algorithmically find real coefficients $a_{n+1},a_{n+2},...\neq 0$ such that the polynomial $p_{n+1}=p_n+a_{n+1}X^{n+1}$ has $n+1$ real roots and that they satisfy 
>   $$
> |r_{n+1}|\geq |r_n|
> $$
>
> For all roots $r_n, r_{n+1}$ of $p_n, p_{n+1}$, respectively.

Does anyone know an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want all the roots from $p_n$ remains the same number for $p_{n+1}$ it is impossible for obvious reason and if that's not the case then you could just let the largest root be your $r_{n+1}$. So what's the problem?

Comment: Let's say I have the polynomial $p=2x^5-73x^4+285x^3+141x^2-1475x+1120$. How do I pick some $a_6$ such that $p+a_6x^6$ has 6 real roots which absolute value greater or equal to all those of $p$?

Comment: Okay, I think I understood the question now.

Comment: Denote the $n+1$ roots of $r_{n+1}$ to be $b_1,b_2,...,b_{n+1}$ where $|b_1|\leq |b_2|\leq ...\leq |b_{n+1}|$ and the $n$ roots of $r_n$ to be $|a_1|\leq |a_2|\leq...\leq |a_n|$. You want $|b_1|\geq |a_n|$ to be satisfied. Now since $|a_0|=|b_1b_2...b_{n+1}|=|a_1a_2...a_n|\leq |b_1b_2...b_n|$ we have $|b_{n+1}|\leq 1$ which implies all $b_i$ are at most one which further implies all $a_i$ are at most one. So if there exist even one root from $p_n$ which is greater than $1$ your problem has no solution.